# Can a giant spoon be utilised as a weapon

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, improvised-weaponry

A player in the group I DM recently rolled a half Orc barbarian and for his main weapon wanted to use a giant spoon he stole from a cloud giant's castle. Would this count as an improvised weapon or as a sort of great club that just happens to look like a spoon?

Comment: Don't use comments for answers, even incomplete ones please.

Comment: What's its weight, length, material, and how's it balanced?

Answer (score 44):

As the DM, it's up to you.

> In many cases, an improvised weapon is similar to an
>   actual weapon and can be treated as such. For example, a
>   table leg is akin to a club. **At the DM’s option**, a character
>   proficient with a weapon can use a similar object as if it
>   were that weapon and use his or her proficiency bonus.

So if you think that a giant's spoon resembles a greatclub, then you can let it have the stats of one and be used identically to one. On the other hand, if you don't think a giant's spoon resembles a greatclub (or any other weapon), then it's an improvised weapon and uses improvised weapon stats.

Comment: Also don't answer in comments on other answers.

Comment: Especially when fighting giant animated bowls of oatmeal. Or eating gelatinous cubes, or any monster that resembles a food of some sort.

Answer (score 7):

The real answer to this question is probably "this is up to the DM".

You could treat it as an improvised weapon (RAW I'd argue), but you could also potentially just reflavour the club as a giant spoon, it's entirely possible and only affects RP rather than rules (which to me is much cooler and better for the player).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48415/discussion-on-answer-by-jamie-brace-can-a-giant-spoon-be-utilised-as-a-weapon).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't waste a second worrying about this. Any character can buy a great club. It's not that unusual or rare a weapon. That your player could come up with such a unique and interesting take on a mundane weapon is nothing short of brilliant and should be allowed. How many barbarians can you name who fight with a spoon stolen from a giant's castle? If it's his main signature weapon, certainly make it better than an improvised weapon.

Allow it? Heck, it's so rule-of-cool I'd reward it. "Yes, and it's a silver spoon. Here come some some werewolves. Roll for initiative!"

Answer (score 0):

Why not just classify your player's giant spoon as a unique Warhammer?

Function and requirements would be similar no matter what the head of the hammer looks like, due to the fact that the mode of operation of the weapon is to swing it, in order to build kinetic energy in the hammer head, to smash into the target.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to do is talk to the player about his/her/their (hereafter referred to by masculine pronouns to save keystrokes) intentions, both in fluff and in crunch.

On the fluff side:
How did he steal it from the giant (presumably being low to mid level)?  And why decide to use it as a weapon?  Is he expecting normal people to recognize his spoon, or just treat him like a kook?

On the crunch side:
Is he expecting the giant spoon to be anything other than a weapon?  Does he expect/plan to use it as a shovel?  Related in part to the fluff, is this a one off item he will use while available, or is he (un)reasonably expecting to be able to easily replace it if it is destroyed or stolen?  Is he okay with not finding magical upgrades, and instead having to commission (pay for and wait for) a magical spoon?

And most importantly, what is he expecting from it as a weapon?  As argued below, the most logical outcome is a one handed weapon similar to a mace or club.  If he is expecting it to be treated like a blunt great axe, he might not be satisified with a mace.  In that case, you may need to work with him to adjust to fluff to fit the crunch.  Or just roll with it, if it won't cause other issues in your campaign.

If the player does not have any specific expecations or requests as to how the spoon works as a weapon, here is is the logic I would use to extrapolate the Cloud Giant's spoon as a weapon.

- [A standard size soup spoon is about 7 inches long](https://www.lifetimesterling.com/Sizes-of-Sterling-Flatware/DIFFERENT_SIZES,default,pg.html).
- [A Cloud Giant is a Huge Class creature.](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Cloud_giant)
- [Huge creatures are approximately 4 times the size of Medium creatures.](http://dungeons.wikia.com/wiki/SRD:Table_of_Creature_Size_and_Scale)

Therefore one can reasonably assume a Cloud Giant's soup spoon to be approximately 28 inches long.  Maybe a little shorter since Cloud Giants are on the small size of Huge.  That would make it just about right for a one handed club or mace.

Personally, I would just make it a mace, with the option to be used as a shovel.  The weight is too far forward for a club.  And thought the spoon's bowl is closer in shape to an axe than a traditional mace head, it is also blunt.  So, just let him use the mace stats and proficiency.  The fact that it can be used to dig is a minor perk that can be offset by social issues.

And he is going to have to handle any future magical upgrades on his own.

One last bit of somewhat relevant trivia.  In the real world, there are entrenching shovels, a military grade shovel designed to be used as both a tool and a backup weapon.  Some even have one edge specifically sharped to make them more axe like

Comment: I don't see how the first four paragraphs are contributing to this answer. You open with a lot of questions, but when you arrive at stat estimates in the last two paragraphs you don't appear to actually do anything with those questions (except mentioning social issues and magical upgrades, which didn't require the questions). Why do all of the questions matter, and why have you raised them? I imagine you had a reason, but I'm left wondering what it is and why I would ask a player any of it, because your second half seemsto demonstrate it doesn't matter because the spoon is the same either way.

Comment: @doppelgreener Because what matters most is the player's desire and intent, and how it will interact with the DM's game and decision.  If the player is expecting the spoon to act like a great axe (only blunt), he probably won't be satisfied with making it a mace or club.  If he doesn't care what kind of weapon it is, then the DM can take the most logical route.  Similarly, if he expects to find magic spoons later, and that doesn't fit the DM's world, that might change the player's mind or require some give and take.

Comment: You should say that, because currently you say "ask them these questions, but also I'd just make it a mace." Sounds like you need to express things to the effect of "depending on the player's preferences, they may prefer it to behave like an axe or a club and won't be satisfied with a mace; talk with them to figure out what they want to get out of it." Right now there's no linkage of the investigation to how you'd mechanise the spoon.

Comment: You might want to consider that the OP didn't specify a soup spoon. It could have been a serving spoon, and thus double the size. Trivial, but it doesn't limit the weapon to the mace category.

Answer (score 0):

The choice is ultimately yours as a DM.

However, a Greatspoon would be a very flexible weapon. It could be used not only as a club, but also as some kind of battleaxe, if the half orc Barbarian sharpened it, as well as some improvised deflective shield if it is large enough. In order to classify the item as best as you can, you should ask him about the combat style he intends to use.

I would personnally go with Improvised Weapon, and give it custom stats depending on the action performed by the barbarian.

Also, on a side note, out of fights, it could be used as a shovel, or even as a cooking pot.